# Whats the best way of asynchronous parsing a CSV file in c#

Tags: c#, csv, asynchronous

I have to parse big CSV files and to improve throughput I am using async and await. My current approach is read the file line by line and perform my own parsing:

```
using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
  string line;
  while ((line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
  {
    // Parse line ...
  }
}
```

However, proper parsing of CSV files is not easy e.g. when strings contain commas etc.

I have been unable to find a CSV parser that both performs well and supports async and await. How can I efficiently parse a CSV file using asynchronous I/O without writing the parser from scratch?

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"  Are you just looking for a speed improvement?  http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Not in the VB Namespace,faster and allows me to use Async Await

Comment: Parsing a file is a CPU-bound operation (unless the file is being read over a network).  There is nothing to make asynchronous.

Comment: @SLaks: It's only CPU-bound if the algorithm is horribly inefficient.

Comment: What would be the purpose of async/await?  Make the UI more responsive?  Just stick it in its own thread, or in a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that's my answer to any potential use of async/await...

Comment: @SLaks Any resources about that? I would assume it's IO bound, but I'm pretty sure I'm wrong :) This one says you're right: http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2008/12/19/parsing-csv-files-is-cpu-bound-a-c-test-case-update-2/, but I'd love to see some .NET benchmarks.

Comment: Did you have a look at the library I linked?

Comment: Parsing a file is I/O bound, I am doing CPU intensive operations as I parse the large files hence wanting to do this asynchronously.  My current code is Awaiting on reader.ReadLineAsync() and processing each time but that won't work if I moved to use TextFieldParser which is why I'm asking if there is a 'better' way...

Comment: @Slaks, so you're suggesting that a 200GB csv file is strictly an IOBound task?  I know the author didn't say it was that large, but we don't rally know how big it is, if it's stored on a network share, etc..  There are lots of reasons such a parsing task might need to be async.  One might even want to parallelize the operation, since unless the CSV refers to other rows it can be easily done that way as well.

Comment: See also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: @Robert: Yes I was just looking at that too :-), it is certainly an option.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/jcoehoorn/EasyCSV I haven't tried it yet with async, but it has potential in that area.

Comment: @JonAlb: I find your question relevant and not off-topic so I have taken the liberty to rewrite it in an attempt to get the question reopened. Please edit my edit or roll it back if you are not satisfied with my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the very useful and easy to use [CsvHelper library](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (also available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)). This even includes built-in [mapping](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping) functionality to map CSV records to objects.

> [**CSV Helper**](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) A .NET library for reading and writing CSV files. Extremely fast, flexible and easy to use. Supports reading and writing
>   of custom class objects.

It isn't asynchronous (as in `async/await`), but as suggested in the comments, you could create your own asynchronous wrapper around it.

Comment: Sounds perfect and looks maintained.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It supports reading of records/rows individually which means this parser can be used within my existing code which Awaiting on  a stream reader using ReadLineAsync().  Great stuff, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on how to combine StreamReader.ReadLineAsync with CvsHelper? TA